# Topological connected group generated by a neighbourhoof of the unit

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Let $G$ be a connected topological group and $V$ an open neighbourhood of the neutral element $e$ with $V=V^{-1}$.

Why is the set $S=\{g_1\cdots g_n,n>0, g_i\in V\}$ open and closed in $G$?

Knowing that together with $e\in S$ would then imply $S=G$.

I found an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282442/a-neighbourhood-of-identity-u-generates-g-where-g-is-a-connected-lie-group) but I do not understand the arguments.

Comment: "but I do not understand the arguments." - you should say what is unclear and add this to the text. Your question in this form is just a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $V^k = \{ g_1\ldots g_k \mid g_i \in V  \}$, then $S = \bigcup_{k > 0} V^k$. Note that $V^2 = \bigcup_{g \in V}L_g(V)$, and since $V$ is open, $L_g(V)$ is open (because $L_g$ is a diffeomorphism), and union of open sets is an open set. By induction, $V^k = \bigcup_{g \in V} L_g(V^{k-1})$ is open. And we conclude that $S$ is open.

For closedness, note that $S = G \setminus \bigcup_{g \not\in S}gS$ is the complement of a closed set.

Comment: With $L_g$ you mean $L_g (h):=gh$? The inverse is $L_{g^{-1}}$ but why are those maps continuous? (This we need to show that $L_g$ is an open map.)

Comment: Yes, $L_g$ denotes left translation by $g$, and $L_g(V)$ is the image of $V$ under $L_g$. The map $L_g$ is continuous by definition of topological group. And it actually an homeomorphism because $(L_g)^{-1} = L_{g^{-1}}$.

Comment: By definition, a topological group is a topological space equipped with a group structure such that multiplication and inversion are continuous maps with respect to the topology given.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps. One last thing: How do you get the equality for the closedness?

Comment: $$G = \bigcup_{g \in G}gS = \bigcup_{g \in S}gS \cup \bigcup_{g\not\in S}gS = S \cup \bigcup_{g \not\in S}gS \implies S = G\setminus \bigcup_{g \not\in S}gS.$$

Comment: The last implication in the last comment is false. But also, the equality $S=G- \cup_{g\notin S} gS$ is simply false, unless $G$ is discrete.  Just think of $G={\mathbb R}$ and $S=(-1,1)$. The complement you wrote in this case equals $\{0\}$.

Comment: You sure? We actually know that $S = \bigcup_{n>0} V^n$... So $S$ cannot be $(-1,1)$.