# The surjectivity of a Lie group homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$ with $H$ connected.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, diffeomorphism

Let $G,H$ be Lie groups with $H$ connected and assume $\phi:G\to H$ is a Lie group homomorphism which is a diffeomorphism onto an open neighbourhood $\mathcal{V}\subset H$ around $e_H$. Does it follow that $\phi$ is surjective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since the image contains an open neighbourhood of the identity, and such a neighbourhood generates the group.

[a neighbourhood of identity $U$ generates $G$ where $G$ is a connected lie group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282442/a-neighbourhood-of-identity-u-generates-g-where-g-is-a-connected-lie-group)