# Can any unitary matrix be written as a product of "2D" unitary matrices?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, unitary-matrices

Given a $n\times n$ unitary matrix $\mathbf{U}$, can this be rewritten as a product
$$
\mathbf{U}=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbf{U}_i
$$
where $\mathbf{U}_i$ are unitary matrices themselves, but they only really `affect' two dimensions?

For $n=3$, they would have this shape (in analogy to the rotation matrices):
$$
\mathbf{U}_1=
\pmatrix{
a_{11}&a_{12}&0\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&0\\
0&0&1},
\quad
\mathbf{U}_2=
\pmatrix{
b_{11}&0&b_{12}\\
0&1&0\\
b_{21}&0&b_{22}},
\mathbf{U}_3=
\pmatrix{
1&0&0\\
0&c_{11}&c_{12}\\
0&c_{21}&c_{22}}
$$
With the 2x2 unitary matrices $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, and $\mathbf{C}$. (Maybe, the ones have to be replaced with a phase factor $e^{i\varphi}$ to have enough flexibility?)

The point is, that I have a property which is preserved under multiplication with such a "2D" unitary matrix. And I suspect that it generalizes to any unitary matrix (ideally even a unitary transformation in $L^2$), but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the map $(U_2)^{n(n-1)/2} \to U_n$ sending a set of "2D" unitary matrices for all choices of the 2 dimensions to the product unitary matrix. It's derivative at $(Id)^{n(n-1)/2}$ is surjective (it sends a 2D skew-Hermitian matrix in the tangent space of the $k$th $U_2$ to the same 2D skew-Hermitian matrix in the selected dimensions, and any skew-Hermitian matrix is a sum of those). Thus the map itself is locally onto (implicit function theorem), so any unitary matrix sufficiently close to $Id$ in $U_n$ is a product of the type you want. But then any unitary matrix is ([a neighbourhood of identity $U$ generates $G$ where $G$ is a connected lie group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282442/a-neighbourhood-of-identity-u-generates-g-where-g-is-a-connected-lie-group)).

Comment: Woah, cool proof!

Comment: One of my profs at some point said that (in pure math) "in the battle of Lie algebra and direct Lie group methods to study Lie groups,  Lie algebra methods won". Not sure 100% true overall, but good to keep in mind sometimes.